# How do I do a many to many relationship in Entity Framework 4.3?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many

I have the following classes:

```
public class Entity
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public abstract ICollection<Entity> Entities {get;set;}
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override ICollection<Entity> Entities {get;set;}
}
```

The mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().Map(
    m => {
            m.ToTable("Children");
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
         });
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasMany(m => m.Entities).WithMany();
```

I get the following exception:

```
The navigation property 'Entities' is not a declared property on type
'EventCriteria'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model
and that it is a valid navigation property.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping TPC inheritance (you call `MapInheritedProperties`) and in that case `Entities` collection must be mapped in your `Base` entity, not in `Child` entity.

Comment: Actually I have another Child class, Child2 which maps to another table "Children2", and  I do not want to use TPT but want to use table per concrete type. That is why I have called map inherited properties.